# Large DB dump import on Mysql on local machine

Tags: database, import, large-data, mysqlimport

After digging many post and doing many R&D on the import process, I didn't find any such solution which can import a large database (Around 15GB+) quickly.

What I tried:

1) Used compressed database to import using following command

```
gunzip < large-db.sql.gz | mysql -u root -p mydb
```

2) Import using source command i.e.

```
mysql -u root -p
use mydb;
set global net_buffer_length=1000000; --Set network buffer length to a large byte number
set global max_allowed_packet=1000000000; --Set maximum allowed packet size to a large byte number
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; --Disable foreign key checking to avoid delays,errors and unwanted behaviour
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 0;
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
source large-db.sql --Import your sql dump file
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 1;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
COMMIT;
```

I found the 2nd option slower than the first option.

Is there anything wrong that I am doing because I read in many posts that the second option works well for others and imports the large database quickly.

For me it takes around 7-8 hours to import as there are 1800 tables with the data.

Comment: Does Option 2 include the time to unzip write to disk?  Note that Option 1 avoids writing to disk.